# Visual Studio, Chart, Axis x point name

Tags: c#, sql, charts

I am creating small program what shows us total sell sum by months via chart, and i need to call X axis points (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) by my SQL response names (2012'7, 2012'8, 2012'9), but cant find how to do this.

[image]

Code:

```
        sqlQuery = "SELECT YEAR(`importdate`) as 'Year', MONTH(`importdate`) as 'Month', SUM(`price`) as 'Sum' FROM `wagon` GROUP BY MONTH(`importdate`), YEAR(`importdate`) ORDER BY YEAR(`importdate`), MONTH(`importdate`) ASC LIMIT 12";

        MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(sqlParams);
        MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);

        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Gainsboro;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Gainsboro;

        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            MySqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (sqlReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    string Sum = sqlReader["Sum"].ToString();
                    if (Sum.Contains(",")) Sum = Sum.Replace(",", ".");

                    string serieName = "Series1";
                   // string serieName = sqlReader["Year"].ToString() + '\'' + sqlReader["Month"].ToString();
                   // chart1.Series.Add(sqlReader["Year"].ToString() + '\'' + sqlReader["Month"].ToString());

                   // chart1.Series[serieName].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";

                    chart1.Series[serieName].Points.AddY(Sum);


                    chart1.Series[serieName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    chart1.Series[serieName].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                    //sqlReader["Year"].ToString() + '"' + sqlReader["Month"].ToString()
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I might be able to help with this one too, but i dont understand this "i need to call X axis points (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) by my SQL response names (2012'7, 2012'8, 2012'9)"

Comment: Thank you, sorry for a bit incomprehensible explanation! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I get you right, you use this:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(0.5, 1.5, "1");
            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(1.5, 2.5, "2");
            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(2.5, 3.5, "3");
            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(3.5, 4.5, "4");
            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(4.5, 5.5, "5");
```

First two numbers determine how far those labels will spread. third is label itself.

Comment: chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(i + 0.5, i + 1.5, sqlReader["Year"].ToString() + '\'' + sqlReader["Month"].ToString()); Works ;) Thank you!